# how to use value loss as benchmark for training again in tensorflow 2.10

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a tensorflow 2.10 model for binary classification.
I have finished training for 10 epochs and saved the best model.
Here I am using ModelCheckpoint callback to save best model.
Now I want to load the weights of best model and train the model again and save the best model.

Here by default on training the second time the model is having benchmark of +inf as loss.
I want that it should calculate the loss on validation set or have the best model loss saved on previous training.
How can I achieve that?

Below is the code I am using:-

```
    model = generate_model(lstm_size, conv_size, num_variables, num_timesteps)
    if(os.path.isfile(checkpoint_filepath)):
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss=focal_loss(), metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
    save_model_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=[save_model_callback])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below implementation of ModelCheckpoint is solving the problem.

```
    model = generate_model(lstm_size, conv_size, num_variables, num_timesteps)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss=focal_loss(), metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
    if(os.path.isfile(checkpoint_filepath)):
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
        validation_loss = float(model.evaluate(test_dataset)[0])
        save_model_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_weights_only=True, verbose=1, initial_value_threshold=validation_loss)
    else:
        save_model_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=[save_model_callback])
```